# SELinux forbids access to httpd userdir

Tags: centos, httpd, selinux

I am running a CentOS machine. I want to serve user directories with Apache, so I configured `httpd.conf` to allow the `public_html` directory.

I have added the `apache` user to my usergroup and `chmod g+xr` the `public_html` and its toplevel directories. If I `su apache`, I can `cd /home/nijansen/public_html` without problems.

When requesting `http://localhost/~nijansen` however, I get a `403 Forbidden` error. I was able to narrow it down to an SELinux issue - it works fine when I disable SELinux.

I have done `/usr/sbin/restorecond ~/public_html` and `ls -Zd ~/public_html` gives me

```
drwxr-x---. nijansen nijansen unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 public_html
```

and `/var/log/httpd/error` just says

```
[Fri Oct 05 20:20:25 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /~nijansen denied
```

Now I am out of ideas and searching for this problem did not give me any so far. I would appreciate a hint in the right direction.

**Update**

For troubleshooting, I have set the SELinux mode to *permissive*, and it does give some logs, but I fail to interpret them:

```
Oct  5 20:50:18 localhost kernel: type=1400 audit(1349463018.930:95232): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=10443 comm="httpd" name="nijansen" dev=dm-6 ino=12058625 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 tclass=dir
Oct  5 20:50:18 localhost kernel: type=1400 audit(1349463018.938:95233): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=10444 comm="httpd" path="/home/nijansen" dev=dm-6 ino=12058625 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 tclass=dir
```

Comment: This should help you considerably http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/08/21/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-a-new-selinux-policy-module/

Answer (score 1):

By filtering the output using `ausearch -m avc | audit2allow` is easy to find the culprit:

```
$ echo "
 Oct  5 20:50:18 localhost kernel: type=1400 audit(1349463018.930:95232): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=10443 comm="httpd" name="nijansen" dev=dm-6 ino=12058625 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 tclass=dir
 Oct  5 20:50:18 localhost kernel: type=1400 audit(1349463018.938:95233): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=10444 comm="httpd" path="/home/nijansen" dev=dm-6 ino=12058625 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 tclass=dir
 " | audit2allow
 ============= httpd_t ==============
 !!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'httpd_enable_homedirs'
allow httpd_t user_home_dir_t:dir { search getattr };
```

To solve this, run as root:

```
 # setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs=on
```